# Why doesn't Vuejs register enabling or disabling my button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a simple Vuejs website in which you can write notes about meetings. Upon loading it takes the meeting notes from the server and displays them. When the user then writes something he can click the "Save" button, which saves the text to the server. When the notes are saved to the server the Save-button needs to be disabled and display a text saying "Saved". When the user then starts writing text again it should enable the button again and display "Save" again. This is a pretty basic functionality I would say, but I'm having trouble with it.

Here's my textarea and my save button:

```
<textarea v-model="selectedMeeting.content" ref="meetingContent"></textarea>
<button v-on:click="saveMeeting" v-bind:disabled="meetingSaved">
    {{ saveMeetingButton.saveText }}
</button>
```

In my Vue app I first initiate my data:

```
data: {
    selectedMeeting: {},
    meetings: [],
    meetingSaved: true,
    saveMeetingButton: {saveText: 'Save Meeting', savedText: 'Saved', disabled: true},
},
```

Upon creation I get the meeting notes from the server:

```
created() {
    axios.get('/ajax/meetings')
        .then(response => {
            this.meetings = response.data;
            this.selectedMeeting = this.meetings[0];
            this.meetingSaved = true;
        });
},
```

I've got a method to save the notes:

```
methods: {
    saveMeeting: function () {
        axios.post('/ajax/meetings/' + this.selectedMeeting.id, this.selectedMeeting)
            .then(function (response) {
                this.selectedMeeting = response.data;
                console.log('Now setting meetingSaved to true');
                this.meetingSaved = true;
                console.log('Done setting meetingSaved to true');
            });
    },
},
```

And I've got a watcher in case something changes to the text which saves the text immediately (this saves with every letter I type, which I of course need to change, but this is just to get started.

```
watch: {
    'selectedMeeting.content': function () {
        this.meetingSaved = false;
        console.log('Changed meeting ', new Date());
        this.saveMeeting();
    }
},
```

If I now type a letter I get this in the logs:

```
Changed meeting  Tue Dec 04 2018 19:14:43 GMT+0100
Now setting meetingSaved to true
Done setting meetingSaved to true
```

The logs are as expected, but the button itself is never disabled. If I remove the watcher the button is always disabled however. Even though the watcher first sets `this.meetingSaved` to `false`, and then `this.saveMeeting()` sets it to `true`, adding the watcher somehow never disables the button.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

Here's a paste of the whole page: https://pastebin.com/x4VZvbr5

Comment: In your watcher, you're calling `this.saveMeeting()`, which means you'll save and disable the button every time you type a character in the `textarea`.  Is this what you want?

Comment: BTW, here's a codesandbox that shows you can enable and disable the button:  https://codesandbox.io/s/5zjl6qzy4k

Comment: Could you check if there is any error in the console? If there is any error during the rendering, it will mean it doesn't deliver an update to the DOM, making it seem like  nothing is happening. My best bet is that ` this.selectedMeeting` gets assigned an `undefined` value

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things going on that could use some changing around.

Firstly the `data` attribute should be a function that returns an object:

```
data() {
    return {
        selectedMeeting: {
            content: null
        },
        meetings: [],
        meetingSaved: true,
        saveMeetingButton: { 
            saveText: 'Save Meeting',
            savedText: 'Saved',
            disabled: true
        },
    };
}
```

This is so Vue can properly bind the properties to *each* instance.

Also, the `content` property of the `selectedMeeting` didn't exist on the initial render so Vue has not added the proper "wrappers" on the property to let things know it updated.

As an aside, this can be done with `Vue.set`

Next, I would suggest you use `async/await` for your promises as it makes it easier to follow.

```
async created() {
    const response = await axios.get('/ajax/meetings');
    this.meetings = response.data;
    this.selectedMeeting = this.meetings[0];
    this.meetingSaved = true;
},
```

For your method I would also write as async/await. You can also use Vue modifiers like `once` on click to only call the api if there is no previous request (think a fast double-click).

```
methods: {
    async saveMeeting () {
        const response = await axios.post('/ajax/meetings/' + this.selectedMeeting.id, this.selectedMeeting);
        this.selectedMeeting = response.data;
        console.log('Now setting meetingSaved to true');
        this.meetingSaved = true;
        console.log('Done setting meetingSaved to true');
    },
},
```

The rest of the code looks okay.

To summarize the main problem is that you didn't return an object in the `data` function and it didn't bind the properties reactively.

Going forward you are going to want to `debounce` the text input firing the api call and also throttle the calls.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately changing the data into a function as you suggest doesn't solve my problem. I added a paste of the whole page to the question. Here it is as well: https://pastebin.com/x4VZvbr5
Does that give you any new ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: The pastebin you have doesn't have the data function, also I think you may want to wrap the promises in $nextTick calls so that the api call doesn't block the UI. You're probably disabling the button but it's enabled again before the ui can rebind.

Comment: The problem is the function in the axios response, it is bound to the wrong this.

I'd recommend using async/await to avoid "callback" hell or if you don't want to Artur's answer will work.

Comment: I know, I reverted it because it didn't solve anything. So it clearly wasn't the problem.

Comment: @kramer65 you still should do this, it is important for Vue. https://flaviocopes.com/vue-data-function/ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 0):

```
this.meetingSaved = true;
```

`this` is referencing `axios` object. Make a reference to vue object outside your call and than use it. Same happens when you use `jQuery.ajax()`.

```
created() {
    var vm = this;
    axios.get('/ajax/meetings')
        .then(response => {
            vm.meetings = response.data;
            vm.selectedMeeting = vm.meetings[0];
            vm.meetingSaved = true;
        });
},
```

Comment: Nice catch, I missed that in my answer since I switched it to async.